# Continuous compactly supported real valued functions on a locally compact and $\sigma$ compact space is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

I already know that if $X$ is a compact metric space then the space of continuous real valued functions $C(X \to \mathbb R)$ are separable. What I'm trying to prove that if $X$ is a locally compact metric space and is $\sigma$-compact. The space of continuous compactly supported functions $C_c( X \to \mathbb R)$ are separable.

---

Here's my approach: As $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, we can write $X = \bigcup_{ n=1}^\infty K_n$, where $K_n$ are compact and increasing. Then since each $C(K_n \to \mathbb R)$ is separable, it suffices to show that the set $ \{ f \in C_c (X \to \mathbb R) : \operatorname{supp}(f) \subset K_n \}$ is dense in $C(X \to \mathbb R)$ (Not sure). Then get I stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then $C(X\to \mathbb{R})$ need not be separable. Is $X$ perhaps required to be a metric space?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, yes. You are right. Fixed.

Comment: I think "$\sigma$-locally compact" is a common abbreviation for "locally compact and $\sigma$-compact". I find it rolls off the tongue more easily.

Comment: Next question: which topology do you take on $C_c(X)$? Uniform convergence?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. The supnorm.

Comment: Are you familiar with Alexandrov compactifications (one-point-compactifications)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Never heard about this. Sorry...

Comment: Pity. That would have made it easy.